# Subtract from one column based on matching values of a second?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data tables:

**A**

```
animal number
dog    11
cat    7
pig    5
```

**B**

```
animal number
dog    1
cat    2
pig    2
pig    3
cat    4
dog    2
```

I would like to subtract the numbers in **A** from the numbers in **B**, based on the matching animal, to get the result...

```
-10
-5
-3
-2
-3
-9
```

I'm sure I can do this without having to write a loop, but have no idea how to do it. I've done quite a bit of searching, but however I'm doing so is not fruiting any results. (Is this where something like how `apply` is used?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose your data frames are `A` and `B`, using `match` is one possibility:

```
B$number - A$number[match(B$animal, A$animal)]
# [1] -10  -5  -3  -2  -3  -9
```

Should you want to append this to `B`, use

```
B$diff <- B$number - A$number[match(B$animal, A$animal)]

#  animal number diff
#1    dog      1  -10
#2    cat      2   -5
#3    pig      2   -3
#4    pig      3   -2
#5    cat      4   -3
#6    dog      2   -9
```

Comment: This is *precisely* what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `merge`:

```
AB <- merge(B, A, by = 'animal', suffixes = c('B','A'))
AB$Subtract_Number <- AB$numberB - AB$numberA

#  AB
#   animal numberB numberA Subtract_Number
# 1    cat       2       7              -5
# 2    cat       4       7              -3
# 3    dog       1      11             -10
# 4    dog       2      11              -9
# 5    pig       2       5              -3
# 6    pig       3       5              -2
```

If there are non-matching animals in the **B** table, you may want to set `all.x = TRUE` in the `merge` function. Note that this will result in `NA` values for `numberA` in the merged table. Although this wasn't specified in the original question, I think @petres made a good point in the comments.

#### data

```
A <- structure(list(animal = c("dog", "cat", "pig"), 
number = c(11L, 7L, 5L)), .Names = c("animal", "number"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

B <- structure(list(animal = c("dog", "cat", "pig", "pig", "cat", "dog"), 
number = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 2L)), .Names = c("animal", "number"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: You maybe should add ```all = TRUE``` and set ```NA``` values to zeros, then it would work!

Comment: @petres I'm not sure that's what OP requested, though

Comment: sorry my fault, thought there were non matching animals in the table!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(A)[B, i.number - number, on = "animal"]
#[1] -10  -5  -3  -2  -3  -9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(B, A, by = 'animal') %>% transmute(animal, number = number.x - number.y)

##   animal number
## 1    dog    -10
## 2    cat     -5
## 3    pig     -3
## 4    pig     -2
## 5    cat     -3
## 6    dog     -9
```

**Edit**

Using `mutate` instead of `transmute` will keep the original columns around by default

```
inner_join(B, A, by = 'animal') %>% mutate(number = number.x - number.y)
```